# Minimal c++ build for armv7,armv7s from command line

Tags: ios, build

I have a very simple source file **foo.cpp**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int foo() {
    printf("foo\n");
    return 11;
}
```

I would like to build an object **foo.o** with architecture armv7. I would like to to this entirely from and command line (i.e. no Xcode projects). First I tried:

```
g++ -arch armv7 -c foo.cpp
```

The error I received was:

```
llvm-g++-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/arm-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IOSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
$IOSROOT/usr/bin/g++ -c foo.cpp -arch armv7s -isysroot $IOSROOT/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk
```

Comment: I haven't tried but my guess is that you would need to replace g++ with clang++.